# setTimeout goes mad after couple of minutes, FF6.0, Chrome 15

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Take a look on my news roller: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t4NXD/11/)**

**Everything works perfectly till you leave scipt in the tab for couple of minutes.**

**What is happening looks like browser lost count of every 5s and is performing action constantly.**

I'm guessing it has something to to with `setTimeout`.

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Script:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.NoticeBoard = function() {


    // Set a timeout
    var timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

    // pause on hover
    $('.noticeboard').hover(

    function() {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }, function() {
        timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);
    });

    // Next notice function called on timeout or click

    function nextNotice(event) {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);

        if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:last-child')) {
            $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300);
            $('.noticeboard span:first-child').fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300).next().fadeIn();
        }
        return false;
    }

    $('#notice-next').click(nextNotice);
    $('#notice-prev').click(function(event) {


        if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:first-child')) {
            $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300);
            $('.noticeboard span:last-child').fadeIn();
        }
        else {
            $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300).prev().fadeIn();
        }
        return false;

    });

};


 })(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.noticeboard span').hide();
$('.noticeboard span:first').show();
$('.noticeboard').NoticeBoard();

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="action-box"> 
<!-- NOTICEBOARD NAV --> 
<a href="#" id="notice-prev">«</a> <a href="#" id="notice-next">»</a> 
<!-- /NOTICEBOARD NAV --> 

<span class="ge"></span>
<div class="noticeboard" style="height: 145px;"> 
    <span style="display: block; opacity: 0.515705;">
        <strong>Boy, 14, found stabbed to death</strong>
        <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-14570107">A 14-year-old boy has been found stabbed to death in a park in north London.</a>
    </span>

    <span style="display: block;">
        <strong>A-level passes rise for 29th year</strong>
        <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/education-14558490">Hundreds of thousands of teenagers are getting their A-level results amid an intense battle for university places ahead of tuition fee rises.</a>
    </span>
    <span style="display: none;">
        <strong>UK: Matter of time for Gaddafi</strong>
        <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-14625484">Deputy Prime Minister Nick Clegg has said it is "only a matter of time" before Col Muammar Gaddafi is defeated.</a>
    </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for providing a fiddle, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried clearing the timeout in the "mouseout" function of your hover?  Just to be doubly sure it was cleared before re-setting it?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem.  I left it for about 5 minutes - and everything still seems ok (Firefox 6.0 on OS X Lion)

Comment: @Aleks - it may be Windows related issue - I'm running windows.

Comment: @numbers1311407 - on mouse out? Let my try this..

Comment: Im running it on Windows in Chrome, so far no problem either.

Comment: Still working fine, I've posted my fiddle version in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found your problem, don't really know how to solve it yet.

I think the issue you are facing is this: when you leave it open in a tab and then you hide the page by selecting another tab and then go back to your page after + 10 seconds(or minutes if you will) that the noticeboard keeps on flashing.

This is probably because jquery can't perform the visual effect when the tab is not currently selected. So it seems to me that it keeps all the effects in a queue and executes them one by one when you return to the tab. Don't know why it does that.

I've added a simple debug line to your nextNotice function to prove that the problem is not setTimeout

Simply add

```
var d = new Date();
$("#debug").append(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + " call to nextNotice<br />");
```

and add a div block somewhere with

```
<div id="debug"></div>
```

That will show you that the call is always made with a 5second delay.

Now to figure out why jquery is queuing the visual effects...

Also copy-pasting from the link in the first comment:

> To avoid this potential problem, use the callback of your last animation in the loop, or append a function to the elements .queue() to set the timeout to start the next animation

So your code should change to this:

```
function nextNotice(event) {
    if ($('.noticeboard span:visible').is('.noticeboard span:last-child')) {
        $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300);
        $('.noticeboard span:first-child').fadeIn(300, function() {timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);});
    } else {
        $('.noticeboard span:visible').fadeOut(300).next().fadeIn(300, function() {timeOut = setTimeout(nextNotice, 5000);});
    }
}
```

This will make sure that the new timeouts are only started when the animation finishes. So if you leave the tab, the last animation that hasn't played will not start a new timeout until you return to the tab.

**Edit**: Formatted code block properly

**Edit 2**: The first comment explains the reason for the problem I describe.

**Edit 3**: Added solution source code

Comment: You've got it.  Check a jQuery doc page about any of the animations.  "Because of the nature of requestAnimationFrame(), you should never queue animations using a setInterval or setTimeout loop. In order to preserve CPU resources, browsers that support requestAnimationFrame will not update animations when the window/tab is not displayed. If you continue to queue animations via setInterval or setTimeout while animation is paused, all of the queued animations will begin playing when the window/tab regains focus."  http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Brilliant! I was just googling on animations via jquery and queuing. Thanx for pointing that out for me!

Comment: Good find, that's quite a cunning problem.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout sets a timer that runs only once.

You might not need to clear it, once the timeout function hits, so try making this change

```
function nextNotice(event) {
    // clearTimeout(timeOut);
```

And see how you get on.
the clearTimeout in the hover is valid though.

Update:

I've moved the function around slightly, it appears to be working fine now, and setting the new timeout after the animation makes it feel a little smoother, he're my fiddle version:

http://jsfiddle.net/t4NXD/20/

Comment: You are right when stating that setTimeout will only execute the function once. Clearing it is indeed unnecessary, but it won't cause any problems either, so removing it is not going to fix anything imo

Comment: Well, clearing it, resetting it, then doing timed animations is likely to cause problems eventually, removing extraneous calls and moving the reset of the timer to after the animation is a better way of doing it, and ultimately better for client performance.

Comment: I agree that it is good practice, and needs to be done. Just adding that this might not be causing anything he experiences.

Comment: I've been running that change for 8 minutes now, it's still fine - although it wasn't wrong for me in the first place ...; to be honest, it was the only odd thing I saw in the code.

Comment: It only gets odd if you leave that tab open in the background and then return to it. See my answer above. It is indeed the only "odd" thing in his code.

Comment: @russ - I have made a video of your example. Can be viewed here: http://www.webinaria.com/video.php?VID=795

Comment: How very bizarre! Anyway, Bram's solution is the correct one anyway; you need to set the timer in the callback function of the last animation frame, so animation events won't get cued whilst you're on a different tab.